# superclass attribute overrides subclass attribute

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have a class with many subclasses,but when passing a subclass instance to some method which is supposed to receive an instance of the superclass, the attribute of the subclass is overwritten.

For example, the following code prints 0. What should I do to it so that it prints the subclass parameter value?

```
class A{
    int cost;
}

class B extends A{
    int cost = 10;
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        method4A(b);

    }

    static void method4A(A a){
        System.out.println(a.cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep 2 differents values, why not setting different variable name?

Comment: Note: pretty sure this has a duplicate somewhere but I can't find it right now...

Comment: Actually it is not overwritten. The object contains both fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While fields can be shared within inheritance, given the right access modifiers (i.e. anything not `private` pretty much - default access will not work across different packages though), they are resolved at compile time, contrary to methods which are resolved at runtime (the latter is called virtual method invocation).

`int`s default to `0`, and you're passing an `A` reference type, so `A.cost`'s value of `0` is printed.

You have a range of options here:

- Do not declare `cost` in `B` and assign `cost` value from `A` in `B`'s constructor, or instance initializer, etc. to `10`
- An ugly, explicit cast in `method4A`, e.g. `System.out.println(((B)a).cost);`
- Passing a `B` reference type instead of `A` in `method4A`
- Keep both `cost` variables and declare a simple getter in `A` returning `cost`, and `@Override` it in `B` with the same implementation (it'll return `B`'s cost even when invoked on a `A` reference if the instance actually is `B`)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem doesn't have any relation with the overriding.

Declaring twice the same field in both classes (class and subclass) may be error-prone.
Do you really need to define two distinct fields ? 
Why not reuse the field of the parent class in the subclass or provide a access to ?

Of course, in some specific cases, it is acceptable and desirable to define two distinct fields but for these cases generally you  use the `private` modifier to isolate them.

A natural way to define such as behavior is providing a `private` field for `cost` and getter and setter in the parent class. 
In this way, the subclass has way to value/set this field.
It could for example value the field from its constructor :

```
class A{

    private int cost;

    public void setCost(int cost){
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public int getCost(){
       return cost;
   }
}

class B extends A{
    public B(){
       this.setCost(10);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        method4A(b);

    }

    static void method4A(A a){
        System.out.println(a.getCost());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method overriding with getters like this:

```
class A {
    int cost;

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

}

class B extends A {
    int cost = 10;

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        method4A(b);
    }

    static void method4A(A a) {
        System.out.println(a.getCost());
    }
}
```